# TypeError when using ngInit (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeerror, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-init

When trying to initialize a variable on load of the view, I get a `TypeError` that appears to be related to an ngRepeat:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null`

I have a bunch of views sharing the same controller, and a parent controller where the var is initially set.  I am using `controllerAs` to avoid scope problems.  The parent controller has `this.submitted = false;` and the child controller has `this.submitted = true;`.  I want to use ngInit in the view HTML to overwrite the parent's var with the child's one...

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label ng-repeat="sample in child.content" 
        ng-init="parent.inputs=child.inputs; 
            parent.submitted=child.submitted;">
        <input id="{{sample.name}}" 
            name="{{sample.name}}" 
            type="{{sample.type}}"
            value="{{sample.value}}"
            ng-model="parent.inputs[sample.name]">
        {{sample.label}}
    </label>
</form>
```

This part seems to work fine:

`parent.inputs=child.inputs`

But this one triggers the TypeError:

`parent.submitted=child.submitted`

Comment: What's the JSON behind? I have the feeling there's some circular referencing somewhere.

Comment: this isn't really what `ng-init` was designed for, especially since `parent` and `child` have no direct relationship to `static`.  I think in order to work out what you are actually trying to accomplish, we need to see more of the HTML and the controller code.

Comment: @Claies - Thanks for pointing out a typo.  The "static" should be "child".  I realize I am using ngInit improperly, but don't know any other way around my dilemma...other than keeping the 2 controllers totally separated, but I was trying to reuse logic by coding DRY.

Comment: @DragosRusu - that's an interesting point.  I will look into that.